# apply custom color scale to pydeck h3hexagon layer

Tags: python, geospatial, deck.gl, pydeck

I am using pydeck to render a visualization using spatial data. I was hoping to use a custom color scale and apply the gradient to the hexagons based on counts.

here's some `json` data:

```
[{"count": "12", "hexIds": ["82beeffffffffff"]}, {"count": "35", "hexIds": ["82be77fffffffff"]}, {"count": "51", "hexIds": ["82b917fffffffff"]}, {"count": "32", "hexIds": ["82bf4ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "93", "hexIds": ["82be67fffffffff"]}, {"count": "51", "hexIds": ["82c997fffffffff"]}, {"count": "13", "hexIds": ["82be5ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "11", "hexIds": ["82bed7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "52", "hexIds": ["82be47fffffffff"]}, {"count": "9", "hexIds": ["82c987fffffffff"]}, {"count": "13", "hexIds": ["82b9a7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "26", "hexIds": ["82a737fffffffff"]}, {"count": "38", "hexIds": ["82be8ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "3", "hexIds": ["829d77fffffffff"]}, {"count": "85", "hexIds": ["82be0ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "12", "hexIds": ["82b9b7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "23", "hexIds": ["82be6ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["82b84ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "6", "hexIds": ["829d4ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "6", "hexIds": ["82b85ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "7", "hexIds": ["82bec7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "32", "hexIds": ["82be57fffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["82a7affffffffff"]}, {"count": "30", "hexIds": ["82a727fffffffff"]}, {"count": "6", "hexIds": ["82a787fffffffff"]}, {"count": "21", "hexIds": ["82bee7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "10", "hexIds": ["82b847fffffffff"]}, {"count": "5", "hexIds": ["82a617fffffffff"]}, {"count": "6", "hexIds": ["82a6a7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "7", "hexIds": ["8294effffffffff"]}, {"count": "17", "hexIds": ["82bef7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["8294e7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "6", "hexIds": ["82a78ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "13", "hexIds": ["82a79ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "3", "hexIds": ["82b877fffffffff"]}, {"count": "5", "hexIds": ["82a797fffffffff"]}, {"count": "28", "hexIds": ["82be4ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "7", "hexIds": ["829487fffffffff"]}, {"count": "4", "hexIds": ["82bedffffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["82945ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "10", "hexIds": ["82b997fffffffff"]}, {"count": "4", "hexIds": ["82b9affffffffff"]}, {"count": "9", "hexIds": ["829c27fffffffff"]}, {"count": "16", "hexIds": ["82a707fffffffff"]}, {"count": "3", "hexIds": ["829d07fffffffff"]}, {"count": "8", "hexIds": ["82c9b7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["8294affffffffff"]}, {"count": "5", "hexIds": ["829d5ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "5", "hexIds": ["829d57fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b80ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "11", "hexIds": ["82beaffffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["82b8b7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["829497fffffffff"]}, {"count": "7", "hexIds": ["829d27fffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["82a7a7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "6", "hexIds": ["82b887fffffffff"]}, {"count": "7", "hexIds": ["829457fffffffff"]}, {"count": "4", "hexIds": ["82c99ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["8294cffffffffff"]}, {"count": "4", "hexIds": ["82b88ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "3", "hexIds": ["82b98ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "7", "hexIds": ["82b837fffffffff"]}, {"count": "9", "hexIds": ["829d0ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["8294c7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "6", "hexIds": ["829d2ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["829d47fffffffff"]}, {"count": "3", "hexIds": ["82b867fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b807fffffffff"]}, {"count": "5", "hexIds": ["82b8a7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["829d67fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82a717fffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["82b82ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["829c6ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "2", "hexIds": ["829c2ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["8294dffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82d897fffffffff"]}, {"count": "8", "hexIds": ["82b86ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b91ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "3", "hexIds": ["82948ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "3", "hexIds": ["829c4ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "5", "hexIds": ["82b897fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b89ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["829c07fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b937fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82949ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b99ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b987fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["8294d7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b8dffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["829ce7fffffffff"]}, {"count": "15", "hexIds": ["82becffffffffff"]}, {"count": "13", "hexIds": ["82be1ffffffffff"]}, {"count": "1", "hexIds": ["82b827fffffffff"]}]
```

```
import pandas as pd
import pydeck
df = pd.read_json('aus_h3.duckgl.json')
h3_layer = pydeck.Layer(
    "H3ClusterLayer",
    df,
    pickable=True,
    stroked=True,
    filled=True,
    extruded=False,
    get_hexagons="hexIds",
    get_fill_color="[255, (1 - count / 500) * 255, 0]",
    get_line_color=[255, 255, 255],
    line_width_min_pixels=2,
)
view_state = pydeck.ViewState(latitude=-25.7773677126431,
                              longitude=135.084939479828,
                              zoom=4,
                              bearing=0,
                              pitch=45)
pydeck.Deck(
    layers=[h3_layer],
    initial_view_state=view_state,
    tooltip={"text": "Density: {count}"}
).to_html("aus_h3.duckgl.html")
```

How do I specify a custom color scale instead on `[255, (1 - count / 500) * 255, 0]` in `get_fill_color` ? For example, I'd like to use 6-class color scale: https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=YlOrRd&n=6

Answer (score 1):

According to the [deck.gl documentation](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/polygon-layer#getfillcolor), `get_fill_color` needs to be an RGB(A) array, or a function returning such an array. The [pydeck documentation](https://deckgl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layer.html#expression-parsers-in-pydeck-objects) says that general functions are not allowed, but expressions using your data as parameters are allowed to be given as strings, so that gives at least two options:

##### Option 1: Linear gradient

Using the color scheme you provided: the brightest color expressed in RGB is `[255,255,178]` and the darkest is `[189,0,38]`.
A linear gradient that spans these colors can be constructed from your data such that the brightest color corresponds to lowest `count` and darkest color to highest `count`:

```
min_count = df['count'].min()
max_count = df['count'].max()
diff = max_count - min_count

color_scheme = f"""[
    255 - (255-189) * (count - {min_count})/{diff}, 
    255 - 255 * (count - {min_count})/{diff}, 
    178 - (178-38) * (count - {min_count})/{diff}
    ]"""
```

This can be passed to the `pydeck.Layer` as `get_fill_color=color_scheme` and gives approximately the same scale as you provided.

##### Option 2: Add the color scheme to the data

Add a new column to the `DataFrame` containing the exact color scheme you want to use. Then the value from that column can be passed as the `get_fill_color`-parameter.
This can be done as such:

```
from math import floor

min_count = df['count'].min()
max_count = df['count'].max()
diff = max_count - min_count

color_scheme = [
        [255,255,178],
        [254,217,118],
        [254, 178, 76],
        [253, 141, 60],
        [240,59,32],
        [189,0,38]
    ]

def get_color(row):
    number_of_colors = len(color_scheme)
    index = floor(number_of_colors * (row['count'] - min_count) / diff)
    # the index might barely go out of bounds, so correct for that:
    if index == number_of_colors:
        index = number_of_colors - 1
    elif index == -1:
        index = 0
    return color_scheme[index]

df['color_column'] = df.apply(get_color, axis=1)
```

And pass this to the `pydeck.Layer` as `get_fill_color="color_column"`.

Comment: could you explain what exactly the function `get_color` is doing?

Comment: using the linear gradient approach, how would I apply `237,248,177 | 127,205,187 |
44,127,184`

Comment: Those 2 examples did not work for me