# Troubleshooting colors in pydeck

Tags: pydeck

I'm having trouble getting colors to work in pydeck (exacerbated by the fact there aren't error messages to hint at the problem). In particular I'm using an `H3ClusterLayer`.

Using an explicit color e.g. `get_fill_color=[0,255,255]` works. The problem is that I'd like to use different colors for different clusters, and I can't get that to work.

Here's a MWE. Working version:

```
import pandas as pd
import pydeck as pdk
from h3 import h3

polygons = [
        {'type' : 'Polygon', 'coordinates' : [[[44,-115],[46,-98],[41,-88],[41,-110]]]},
        {'type' : 'Polygon', 'coordinates' : [[[38,-110],[39,-88],[34,-92],[36,-118]]]},
        ]
hexes = [list(h3.polyfill(polygon, 3)) for polygon in polygons]
color = [
        [0,255,255],
        [200, 100, 0],
        ]
tooltip = ['foo', 'bar']

df = pd.DataFrame({'tooltip' : tooltip, 'hexes' : hexes, 'color' : color})

layer = pdk.Layer(
        'H3ClusterLayer',
        df,
        pickable=True,
        stroked=False,
        filled=True,
        extruded=False,
        opacity=0.25,
        get_hexagons='hexes',
        get_fill_color=[0,255,255],
)

view_state = pdk.ViewState(latitude=38.2, longitude=-96.9, zoom=4, bearing=0, pitch=0)
r = pdk.Deck(
        layers=[layer],
        map_style='light',
        initial_view_state=view_state,
        tooltip={'text' : '{tooltip}'}
)
r.to_html("test.html")
```

For me the output looks like this:
[image: working version]

Broken version: exactly the same, but changing `get_fill_color=[0,255,255]` to `get_fill_color='color'`. I expect this to work based on the documentation, but instead the result looks like this:
[image: broken version]

I can tell that something is happening because the tooltip still appears over where the hexes should be, but the hexes themselves don't appear.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when using ```get_fill_color='color'```? I dont know PyDeck but shouldn't it be ```get_fill_color=color[1]``` if you want to use your defined colors?

Comment: Or ```get_fill_color=f'{color[1]}'``` if you want to pass it as string

Comment: I'm expecting the [expression parser](https://deckgl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layer.html#expression-parsers-in-pydeck-objects) to understand `'color'` as a column name in `df` and get the colors from there---the same way that the argument `get_hexagons='hexes'` just takes the column name and gets the data from the dataframe.

Comment: cf. also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076494/apply-custom-color-scale-to-pydeck-h3hexagon-layer)---what I'm trying to do is Option 2 in that answer, and it's not working for me.